# In Sylius, how to filter product show according to user role?

Tags: symfony, sylius

I would like to show some products to users having the good role, and not to others. 
Does anyone know if there is a defined way to do that, or do I need to override the Product Model to add an attribute and modify queries in order to filter according to the current user roles ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I think you can override the ProductRepository, inject `sylius.context.customer`and override the method `createListQueryBuilder` to take the user role into consideration.